# Evaluate $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{255}\sqrt[4]{k+1}-\sqrt[4]{k}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Evaluate $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{255}\sqrt[4]{k+1}-\sqrt[4]{k}$

Answer 3

I tried writing it in the formula but I always have a $\sqrt[4]{255}$ that I can't do anything with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author of the problem meant for the "+" in the middle to be a "-". Otherwise it's not true. How do I know?

The 4th root of 16 is 2; so the 16th term contains both that and the 4th root fo 17, which is larger, so the sum is at least 4.

Oh...I see. You've changed the sign now. Well, that's easy;

The sum looks like this

$(B-A) + (C-B) + ... + (Q - P)$

All the terms cancel except the first and last, $A - P$. The first is 
the $A =$ 4th root of 1, which is 1. The last is the fourth root of 256, which is 4. And $4 - 1 = 3$.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistyping

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

A more general concept is called [telescoping sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html).

With that, you would also be able to give an answer to the following exercise:

$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2016}\sqrt[5]{k+1}-\sqrt[5]{k}=?
$$